# why this Component only works on start but not when pressing button

Tags: react-redux, react-component

I learn React-Redux and need help understanding why this Component only works on start but not when I press the button.
When debug start the breakpoints in the picture break execution but when I press the button I get this error showed in the picture.

When breakpoints hit I hoower over the `{toasts.map(toast => {` and the Array size is zero. But when I press button the breakpoints does not even hit

Any ide?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

I have this configureStore.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { forbiddenWordsMiddleware } from "../middleware";
import  ToastsReducer from '../reducers/ToastsReducer';
import  RootReducer from '../reducers/RootReducer';

const storeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const reducers = {
     toastsReducer: ToastsReducer,
     rootReducer: RootReducer
  };

  const reduce = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
  });

const store = createStore(
    reduce,
    storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(forbiddenWordsMiddleware))
);
export default store;
```

RootReducer.js

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";
import { FOUND_BAD_WORD } from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
  articles: []
};
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === ADD_ARTICLE) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      articles: state.articles.concat(action.payload)
    });
  }

  if (action.type === FOUND_BAD_WORD) {
    //return Object.assign({}, state, {
    //  articles: state.articles.concat(action.payload)
    // });
  }
  return state;
}
```

ToastsReducer.js

```
import { ADD_TOAST, REMOVE_TOAST } from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
  toastList: []
};

export default function toasts(state = initialState, action) {
  const { payload, type } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case ADD_TOAST:
      return [payload, state.toastList];

    case REMOVE_TOAST:
      return state.toastList.filter(toast => toast.id !== payload);

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Picture showing RootReducer.jsx  and Toasts.jsx when I press button two times, 
[image]

Toast.js

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Toast extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="toast" style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.color }}>
        <p className="toast__content">
          {this.props.text}
        </p>
        <button className="toast__dismiss" onClick={this.props.onDismissClick}>
          x
        </button>
      </li>
    );
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }
}

Toast.propTypes = {
  color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onDismissClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Toast;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share your reducer code. Most likely, you have not set an initial state for toastList in the reducer or  there is an error with `toastsReducer.toastList`.

Try the following:

- Change line 34 to `toasts: state.toastsReducer`
- Comment the lines from 10 to 19 and insert the following to make sure toasts is an array.

```
console.log(toasts);
console.log(toasts.toastList);
return null;
```

If both are undefined, then the value returned by the reducer is not right.

In ToastsReducer.js:

Change the following:

```
 case ADD_TOAST:
      return [ ...state.toastList, payload]; //<--- Here
```

When you do return[payload,state.toastList], it appends another array to the toastList.

Run the following to see:

```js
toastList = ['abc'];

// Right way to add an item to an array.
toastList = [...toastList, 'def'];

console.log(toastList);
console.log('-----');
// Adds an array to the array. Incorrect way.
toastList = [toastList, 'ghi'];

console.log(toastList);
```

---UPDATE---

Change your ADD_TOAST case to:

```
return { toastList: [...state.toastList, payload] };
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: I added reducer code. Thanks I did what you say and get in debug log when I press button three times:- ....Array(2) [Object, undefined]
Toasts.jsx:10
undefined
Toasts.jsx:11
....Array(2) [Object, undefined]
Toasts.jsx:10
undefined
Toasts.jsx:11
....Array(2) [Object, undefined]
Toasts.jsx:10
undefined

Comment: Even after changing the ADD_TOAST case to what I suggested?

Comment: When I change the ADD_TOAST and press button I get in the log `Array(1) [Object]
Toasts.jsx:10
undefined`, when I press button again I get  - TypeError: state.toastList is not iterable

Comment: Can you update the question with the new changes in ToastsReducer.js and Toasts.jsx?

Comment: I have this project at [github](https://github.com/erikswed/ReactTodoWithToast) hope you can see what´s wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just do check your `toasts` array contains data,

```
{toasts && toasts.length > 0 ? toasts.map(toast => {...}) : null}
```

Comment: Thanks when I do that I get `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. So the map is not null but something else

Comment: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` this error also means that your `toasts` array is not being passed to this component. Make sure it has value before calling this component.